# Python 3 Paramiko using SCP

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I'm trying to use SCP based on this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scp

I try running the following:

```
def scpImport():
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
    ssh.connect("IP", port=22)
    with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
        scp.put('test.txt')
```

However, my program says:

```
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 288, in connect
server_key)
TypeError: missing_host_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Is it because I have no form of authentication for ssh? Do I need to pass in private/public keys on my connect statement? If so, I'm unsure how to do this because there are very few examples for this module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
```

instead of:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
```

to set an instance and not the class itself.

Comment: Sometimes I overlook the simplest mistakes...Thanks